# initiating http post request from html form and receiving that request in java

Tags: java, html, http, httprequest

i am running a simple web server in java that is running on port 8080 on my machine , the server do receive request that come from browsers (when i write this URL (localhost:8080) ) however i wanted to receive request that come from this html page

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="192.168.1.1:8080">
            <input type="text" name ="txt">
            <input type="submit" name="sub">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result was The webpage cannot be displayed

and my second try was this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="server.java">
                <input type="text" name ="txt">
                <input type="submit" name="sub">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and after i clicked the submit button it opened the download dialog (download server.java).

however i managed to initiate a request on my own in java

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",8080);
    String request = "get / http/1.1";
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    os.write(request.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

and my server received that request with no problems , i am not sure what am I missing here and what is that layer that initiate a correct request to a php website for example.

Comment: Writing a web server is a non trivial task, especially if you dont have a sound understanding of HTTP. And how shall we debug your server code if you dont give us a single line of code from it??

Comment: you dont really need to see my web server code , cause my problem is in initiating a request from html as i mentioned .

Comment: At least the second example should give you a hint that there is SOMETHING happening with the POST request. Again, you are perhaps the only person on earth who knows what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a scripting language and does not work like php or perl. In your server you should map request URI to handling code (e.g. in web.xml). In your <form action="..."> you should provide an URI which your server will handle.